# How to set text of item on selected edittext view?

Tags: android, android-studio, view, android-edittext

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ext5N.jpg)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jHrg.jpg)

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElLbm.jpg)

I want to avoid set text on other edittext.
I want to set text of alert list dialog's item on which I clicked editext.

> **You can undersand my problem from above images. I can't set text on which I have to. I want to set text on first edittext but value is setting on recently created view.**

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity
{
    LinearLayout parent_linear_layout;
    EditText editText;
    String value;
    Button add;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        parent_linear_layout = findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout);
        add = findViewById(R.id.button_add);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                addView();
            }
        });
    }

    private void addView()
    {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_add_language2, null, false);
        parent_linear_layout.addView(view);
        editText = view.findViewById(R.id.et_name2);
        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                simpleDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    public void simpleDialog()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Select names");
        String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.language);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(array, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
            {
                value = array[i];
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
            {
                editText.setText(value);
            }
        });
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: No Sir, I don't think we understand your problem from the images. Please describe the problem in more detail. And please include the activity_layout file as well.

Comment: When you call addView() you replace whatever editText was before.

Comment: So what's solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this code, but the idea is to always pass the clicked edittext to simpleDialog so it sets the text in the correct one and not the newest one.

```
private void addView(){
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_add_language2, null, false);
    parent_linear_layout.addView(view);
    EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.et_name2);
    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            EditText et = (EditText) view
            simpleDialog(et);
        }
    });
}

public void simpleDialog(EditText editText)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select names");
    String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.language);
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(array, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
        {
            value = array[i];
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
        {
            editText.setText(value);
        }
    });
    builder.create();
    builder.show();
}
```